# Why is WCF performance so slow when compared with Remoting?

Tags: .net, wcf, remoting

I'm trying to evaluate which communication technology to use in a new system, right now it looks like Remoting is our only option as WCF's performance is terrible.

I have benchmarked calling a WCF service hosted in IIS7 using nettcp, compared to calling a remoting interface hosted in a console app.  The WCF service takes ~4.5 seconds to perform 1000 requests, synchronusoly on an endpoint (which simply returns back a new instantce of an object).  The remoting client takes < 0.5 second to perform the same task.

Here is the WCF client code:

```
public class TcpNewsService : INewsService
{
    private INewsService _service = null;

    Lazy<ChannelFactory<INewsService>> _newsFactory = new Lazy<ChannelFactory<INewsService>>(() =>
    {
        var tcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding
            {
                //MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue,
                //MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
                //MaxConnections = int.MaxValue,
                //MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue,
                PortSharingEnabled=false,
                TransactionFlow = false,
                ListenBacklog = int.MaxValue,
                Security = new NetTcpSecurity 
                { 
                    Mode = SecurityMode.None, 
                    Transport = new TcpTransportSecurity
                    {
                         ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.None,
                         ClientCredentialType = TcpClientCredentialType.None
                    },
                    Message = new MessageSecurityOverTcp 
                    { 
                        ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None } 
                    },
                ReliableSession = new OptionalReliableSession { Enabled = false }
            };
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:8089/NewsService.svc");
        return new ChannelFactory<INewsService>(tcpBinding, endpointAddress);
    });

    public TcpNewsService()
    {
        _service = _newsFactory.Value.CreateChannel();
        ((ICommunicationObject)_service).Open();

    }

    public List<NewsItem> GetNews()
    {
        return _service.GetNews();
    }
}
```

And a simple console app to invoke the client code:

```
var client = new TcpNewsService();

Console.WriteLine("Getting all news");

var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var news = client.GetNews();
}
sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Finished in " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
Console.ReadLine();
```

The web.config file for the IIS host looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="NewsServiceBehavior" name="RiaSpike.News.Service.NewsService">
    <endpoint address=""
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding"
          contract="RiaSpike.News.Types.INewsService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="http://localhost:8094/NewsService.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="httpBinding"
          contract="RiaSpike.News.Types.INewsService">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="NewsServiceBehavior">
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="httpBinding">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="tcpBinding" portSharingEnabled="false">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
      <reliableSession enabled="false"  />
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
```

And the service class hosted in IIS:

```
[ServiceBehavior(
    ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
    InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
    AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any
)]

public class NewsService : MarshalByRefObject, INewsService
{

    public List<NewsItem> GetNews()
    {
        return new List<NewsItem> 
            { 
                new NewsItem { Descripion = "The Description", Id = 1, Title = "The Title"}
            };
    }
}
```

I have traced the WCF activity and have seen the process take approximately 5 millisconds to complete (I couldn't upload animage, here's one acivity trace from the log)

From: Processing message 5.   Transfer    3/12/2010 15:35:58.861
Activity boundary. Start 3/12/2010 15:35:58.861
Received a message over a channel. Information 3/12/2010 15:35:58.861
To: Execute 'Ria.Spike.News.INewsService.GetNews' Transfer 3/12/2010 15:35:58.864
Activity boundary. Suspend 3/12/2010 15:35:58.864
From: Execute 'Ria.Spike.News.INewsService.GetNews' Transfer 3/12/2010 15:35:58.864
Activity boundary. Resume 3/12/2010 15:35:58.864
Sent a message over a channel Information 3/12/2010 15:35:58.866
Activity boundary. Stop 3/12/2010 15:35:58.866

Is this as good as it gets :s

Here's the remoting code used in this example.

```
var  iserver = (INewsService)Activator.GetObject(typeof(INewsService), "tcp://127.0.0.1:9000/news");
var sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    var news = iserver.GetNews();
}

sw.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Finished in " + sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);
Console.ReadLine();
```

And a the TCP endpoint for this remoting channel hosting in IIS:

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    private TcpServerChannel _quote; 

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _quote = new TcpServerChannel(9000);
        if (ChannelServices.RegisteredChannels.Length ==0)
        {
            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(_quote, false);    
        }


        RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(
        typeof(NewsService),
        "news",
        WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);

        _quote.StartListening(null);      
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be of interest to see if there is a startup penalty for the WCF version. Could you try a run where the sw isn't started until the call is made at least once and post the results?

Comment: Hi Peter, I did actually invoke the 1000 call iteration twice to illiminate the starup cost.  The time difference between the first and second was negligible.

Comment: What is your remoting configuration?

Comment: Added the Remoting code above, its beauty is its simplicity :D

Comment: You may want to test with REST also, as SOAP will be slower, just due to overhead.

Comment: To perform a proper test, I think you should host the WCF service in a console host as well - remove one of the variations. Though like James, I suspect the problem is that remoting is using binary encoding while netTcp is using SOAP encoding.

Comment: So even though I'm using netTcp, which defaults to binary format, the DataContractSerializer is still generating XML, just that it transmits this over the wire in binary.  Is there no solution then for WCF to use a binary serializer rather than and xml one with a binary formatter?

Comment: @gav: what makes you think that the binary XML format is the problem? Also, you should feel free to use Remoting if you don't care that your application will start off life being obsolete. Otherwise, you should probably try to find the problem and fix it, as most of us don't see the problem you do.

Comment: @gav: also, why do you have a basicHttpBinding in there? I'm pretty sure that IIS does not support net.tcp. I bet you're actually using http.

Comment: @John, The http binding was left there just for my testing.  As you can see the client code connects on the tcp binding, so this configuration is using tcp.  IIS 7 most certianly does support hosting a wcf netTcp service, ask Google.

Comment: @gav: I have reason to believe you are mistaken. You can prove it to me by removing that http endpoint and seeing what happens. Also, please post the .svc file.

Answer (score 9):

This tests sequential, synchronous, calls only.  An IIS hosted WCF service provides more infrastructure to handle a higher load and will likely out-perform remoting for a high-load test (one with a lot of concurrent connections).

A remoting endpoint can also be hosted in IIS though to get the same advantages.  WCF can also be hosted in a console.  You're really comparing apples to oranges here.